# Facebook Programming Challenge - ByteLand

Tags: facebook, algorithm

ByteLand 
Byteland consists of N cities numbered 1..N. There are M roads connecting some pairs of cities. There are two army divisions, A and B, which protect the kingdom. Each city is either protected by army division A or by army division B.

You are the ruler of an enemy kingdom and have devised a plan to destroy Byteland. Your plan is to destroy all the roads in Byteland disrupting all communication. If you attack any road, the armies from both the cities that the road connects comes for its defense. You realize that your attack will fail if there are soldiers from both armies A and B defending any road.

So you decide that before carrying out this plan, you will attack some of the cities and defeat the army located in the city to make your plan possible. However, this is considerably more difficult. You have estimated that defeating the army located in city i will take up ci amount of resources. Your aim now is to decide which cities to attack so that your cost is minimum and no road should be protected from both armies A and B.

----Please tell me if this approach is correct----

We need to sort the cities in terms of resources required to destroy the city. For each city we need to ask the following questions:

1) Did deletion of the previous city NOT result into a state which can destroy Byteland?

2) Does it connect any road?

3) Does it connect any road which is armed by a different city?

If all of these conditions are true, we'll proceed towards destroying the city and record the total cost incurred so far and also determine if destruction of this city will lead to overall destruction of Byteland.

Since the cities are arranged in increasing order of the cost incurred, we can stop wherever we find the desired set of deletions.

Comment: ...and your question would be? If you're asking us to just solve the problem for you, you're likely to be disappointed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin..of course not..I was editing the question to post my approach.

Comment: You'll have to provide a bounty just for reading this...

Comment: minimum vertex cover is answer.. google it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only care about roads that link two cities with different armies - links between A and B or links between B and A, so let's delete all links from A to A or B to B.

You want to find a set of points such that each link has at least one point on it, which is a minimum weight vertex cover. On an arbitrary graph this would be NP-complete. However, your graph only ever has nodes of type A linked to nodes of type B, or the reverse - it is a bipartite graph with these two types of nodes as the two parties. So you can find a minimum weight vertex cover by using an algorithm for finding minimum weight vertex covers on bipartite graphs. Searching for this, I find e.g. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-854j-advanced-algorithms-fall-2008/assignments/sol5.pdf

Answer (score 1):

mcdowella,

But the vertices have a cost to them and the minimum vertex cover would not produce the right vertices to remove. Imagine 2 vertices (A army) pointing to the third one (B). First two vertices cost 1 each, where the third one costs 5. A minimum vertex cover would return the third one - but removing the third one costs more than removing both nodes with cost 1 + 1.

We would probably need some modified version of a minimum vertex cover here.